# Ninject - Extracting instance instantiation to a separate project / class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to extract Binding of interfaces to classes that implement them and instance instantiation to a separate project.

This is what I have so far:

```
 public class DependencyModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>();
        }
    }
```

This is my module.
And in this class I want to create a static method, that when passed any interface tries to find class that's bind to it and return an instance of it:

```
public static class Resolver<T, U>
    {
        public static T GetInstance<T>(U requestedInterfaceInstance)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new DependencyModule());

            return kernel.Get<requestedInterfaceInstance>();
        }
    }
```

So, My guess is that I need two type parameters? One for return type of the object I want to return (e.g MyClass instance), and one for my method parameter, which in this case would be (IMyClass).

How can I accomplish this in a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- the kernel should not be recreated for every request / instantiation. Create the kernel once (new Standardkernel()...) and then use the same instance for each request
- what you did implement is the so called [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern. The idea of ninject and Dependency-Injection containers in general is to follow the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern/) pattern. Ideally there should only be one call to `kernel.Get<>` - for the root component. All other components are injected into the root component.
- in case at some point you really need to specifically create an instance - not by constructor injection - you should use the [Abstract Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) pattern. Alternatively and simpler, use the [ninject factory extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory)